# Flex TreeGrid Query

Tags: apache-flex, treegrid

Can anyone tell me the equivalent of osflex:TreeGridCellRenderer for the flexlib package?

Answer (score 0):

The AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer is the equivalent class. This renders the grouping field for the AdvancedDataGrid which is the tree grid class in flex